# facebook photo upload inside joomla 2.5

Tags: php, facebook, joomla

I am using php code to upload photos to facebook within a joomla article, I have everything working but for some reason the code is producing two login links and when processed it uploads the photo to the album twice. can someone please help with this? attched code that I am using.

```
<?php
    require_once('fb-image-upload/config.php');
    require_once('fb-image-upload/fb_wrapper_class.php');
    $redirectURL    =   "http://zainylayouts.com/facebook-covers";
    $fbObj          =   new FaceBookWrapper(APP_ID, SECRET_ID, $redirectURL);
?>

<a href ="<?php echo $fbObj->getLoginURL();?>">Login</a>

<?php 
    $fbObj->addPhoto('images/timeline_covers/sports/snowsports_timeline_cover.jpg', 'Snow Sports Facebook Cover', 'New Album', 'Testing Album');
?>
```

Comment: Nothing in that code is likely to be the issue.

Comment: I cant figure it out! I just went to the page that has the code in it and it just automatically posted the image to my facebook multiple times without even clicking on the button. There as got to be something not working right with this code

Comment: That code looks pretty straightforward, but it also looks like something that wouldn't be running standalone by itself - it'd be called by some other piece of code, which is likely the culprit.

Comment: I am not a coder at all, far from it. I purchased the the code and am trying to add it within a joomla based article. I could use some help with it and it would be greatly appreciated and would even be willing to pay for some help with it. What I am trying to accomplish is have a link buttun that would upload the image to facebook. as it is right now, if you click on one of the login buttons it will give desired results and seems to work, but if you refresh the page that has this code it it will upload the image again. I am stuck here.

Comment: Is there a way to call on this code without having it in the page? like say a button? when clicked it will run this code, go to app so user can login and accept it then upload the image?

Comment: Is this code placed inside a plugin event? If that is the case, some of the events are called multiple times.